# trying to return a hash from a perl function and getting "can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref...."

Tags: perl, hash, strict

I have a Perl function (named readDicomFile) which ends thusly:

```
return { 'fileProperties' => \%fileProperties, 'filehandle' => *FH, 'buffersize' => $buffersize };
```

the code that calls it looks like this:

```
$file = readDicomFile( $ARGV[0] );
#use Data::Dumper;
#print Dumper $file;
my @imageData;
local *FH = $file->{filehandle};
while ( read(FH, $_, $file->{buffersize}) ) {
  push @imageData, unpack( 'S' x ( $file->{buffersize}/($file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}/8) ), $_ );
}
print "DEBUG: found ", (scalar @imageData), " elements\n";
```

I get this output:

```
Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./test.pl line 17.
DEBUG: found 262156 elements
```

When I try to figure out what's happening with my data structure, I uncomment the two lines for using Data::Dumper and I get this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fileProperties' => {
                                'echoNumber' => '',
                                'highBit' => 11,
                                'rows' => 512,
                                'bitsAllocated' => 16,
                                'modality' => 'CT',
                                'echoTime' => '',
                                'windowCenter' => '200',
                                'studyDescription' => 'CT SINUS / FACIAL WITH CONTRAST ',
                                'repetitionTime' => '',
                                'sequenceName' => '',
                                'method' => 'perl method',
                                'seriesNumber' => '502 ',
                                'imageNumber' => '0 ',
                                'windowWidth' => '50',
                                'trailer' => 0,
                                'pixelRepresentation' => 0,
                                'sliceLocation' => '',
                                'bitsStored' => 12,
                                'ultrasoundColorData' => '',
                                'rescaleIntercept' => 0,
                                'photometricInterpretation' => 'MONOCHROME2 ',
                                'description' => 'Patient Protocol',
                                'imageDataType' => '',
                                'imagePosition' => '',
                                'columns' => 512,
                                'studyDate' => '20140505'
                              },
          'filehandle' => *Radiology::Images::FH,
          'buffersize' => '1024'
        };
```

I've played around with several different idioms for returning the hash values from the function (like passing back a hash or a hashref), but I'm always getting the same error.

Does anyone have insight into my problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've been playing around with this all afternoon. Here is the entirety of the current test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use lib '/etc/perl';
use strict;
use Radiology::Images;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
$file = readDicomFile( $file );
print STDERR "DEBUG: $file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}\n";
my @imageData;
# while ( $readsize = read ( $file->{filehandle}, $_, $file->{buffersize} ) ) {
#    push @imageData, unpack( 'S' x ( $file->{buffersize}/($file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}/8) ), $_ );
# }
my $readsize;
my $imagesize = $file->{fileProperties}->{columns} * $file->{fileProperties}->{rows};
print "DEBUG: should find $imagesize elements\n";
while ( $imagesize > 0 ) {
  $readsize = read ( $file->{filehandle}, $_, $file->{buffersize} );
  push @imageData, unpack( 'S' x ( $readsize/( $file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}/8 ) ), $_ );
  $imagesize -= $readsize /( $file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}/8 );
}
print "DEBUG: found ", (scalar @imageData), " elements\n";
```

...which gives me this output

```
DEBUG: 16
DEBUG: should find 262144 elements
Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /root/test.pl line 7.
DEBUG: found 262144 elements
```

...HOWEVER, when I change the 'while' loop in line #15 to

```
while ( $imagesize > 34816 ) {
```

I get this output:

```
DEBUG: 16
DEBUG: should find 262144 elements
DEBUG: found 227328 elements
```

So, it would appear that something I'm doing in a loop between lines 15 and 18 causes an error that goes back in time to line 7. Thus, my problem has *never* been with passing the hash back from my function. ??

BTW, the number 34816 was arrived experimentally. 34816 doesn't trigger the error, 34815 does.

Given this is looking completely whacky and given that the code works the way I think it is supposed to despite the error, I guess I'll just assume it is a language bug and turn my attention to just suppressing the error message.

2nd EDIT:

This is test.pl now:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use lib '/etc/perl';
use strict;
use Radiology::Images;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
$file = readDicomFile( $file );
my @imageData;
my $readsize;
while ( $readsize = read ( $file->{filehandle}, $_, $file->{buffersize} ) ) {
  push @imageData, unpack( 'S' x ( $readsize/($file->{fileProperties}->{bitsAllocated}/8) ), $_ );
}
print "DEBUG: found ", (scalar @imageData), " elements\n";
```

gives me this output:

```
Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /root/test.pl line 9.
DEBUG: found 5638203 elements
```

if I comment out the 'use strict' line, I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value in ref-to-glob cast at /root/test.pl line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in read at /root/test.pl line 9.
read() on unopened filehandle at /root/test.pl line 9.
DEBUG: found 5638215 elements
```

I, uh, obviously...don't understand this....

Comment: what is line 17?  what is readDicomFile?  is the script you are running test.pl or are you running test.pl from within this script?  (all the code you show should work as is, though Miller's suggestion to use a lexical filehandle is a good one)

Comment: readDicomFile is the function containing the 'return' statement. test.pl is a short program I put together to validate my function's output.

Comment: @BrysonBorg What is line 17?

Comment: @Miller: I updated my question with additional information. It turns out that the line number given by the error message is whatever line contains uses the $file hashref, but what *triggers* the error is something that happens later in whatever loop is reading from the $file->{filehandle}. Wierd.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Miller: For context: &readDicomFile is a function to read dicom files (medical imaging). There is a lot of heterogeneity in the format of the data payload in these files, so &readDicomFile forks, with the child writing standardized data (unsigned, 2 bytes per pixel) to a filehandle, and the parent passing the metadata and the filehandle back to the application. Given that, modulo the error, everything seems to be working, I ended up wrapping the access to the hashref in an eval{}; to suppress the error in my server logs. Not the way I'd prefer to do things, but the best I can come up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a reference to your file handle:

```
return {
    'fileProperties' => \%fileProperties,
    'filehandle'     => \*FH,              # <--- reference.
    'buffersize'     => $buffersize,
};
```

And then when reading, you can work directly on the filehandle, you don't have to transfer it to a fileglob:

```
# local *FH = $file->{filehandle};  <--- Not Needed. Below, just use the lexical fh
while ( read($file->{filehandle}, $_, $file->{buffersize}) ) {
```

If you work with lexical file handles from the very beginning, it becomes a lot more obvious how to pass them:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die "Can't open: $!";

return {
    'fileProperties' => \%fileProperties,
    'filehandle'     => $fh,
    'buffersize'     => $buffersize,
};
```

Comment: using a glob instead of a globref won't cause the error the OP is seeing.

Comment: I tried this and it worked exactly the same as my original code. Thanks, though.